# Save/load contents of binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

So I've looked around a lot for some information on how to take elements from a binary search tree and write them to a file, and then later read them back into the tree as a type of "load" function. I've found a few ways that people go about it, but I am having issues implementing those suggestions such as the one seen here, into my program itself. So I have several sort methods, inOrder, postOrder, and preOrder, but don't necessarily need to write to the file every time one of those methods is called. I would like to have a saveFile and a loadFile method that would automatically write/read when called, but do I have to call the writer/reader in those sort methods to get every node in the BST? Or can I have methods that will do it outside? They don't necessarily need to be sorted into the file, because the program will do that within itself. What are some suggestions about going about this?

Here is an example of one of my sort classes (which is called from a seperate menu class giving the user the option to choose how it should be sorted:

```
public void inOrderTraverseTree (Node focusNode) {
    if (focusNode != null){
        inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild);

        System.out.println(focusNode);

        inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild);
    }//end if
}//end inOrderTraverseTree
```

And an example of when it's called (from the menu class, in a switch):

```
case 1:
    tree.inOrderTraverseTree(tree.root);
    menu();
    break;
```

Please let me know suggestions! thank you!

Comment: Any order will work as long as your inserts work correctly and balance your tree, but I think a preorder traversal will maintain the current structure if it's unbalanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.println` writes to standard output, not to file. It is possible to redirect that output to a file, either through code (which you shouldn't be doing) or through the command-line, which is pretty simple using a pipe (I think `|` in Linux, `>` in Windows), but does have some disadvantages.

Another option would be to pass an `OutputStream` to your function, perhaps a `PrintStream` if you like your `println` method.

```
public void inOrderTraverseTree (Node focusNode, PrintStream printStream) {
    if (focusNode != null){
        inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild, printStream);
        printStream.println(focusNode);
        inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild, printStream);
    }//end if
}//end inOrderTraverseTree
```

To print it to a file, you could use:

```
inOrderTraverseTree(root, new PrintStream("fileName"));
```

Note that the `new` call will clear out the file before starting, so you'd probably want to store the `PrintStream` in a temporary variable, passing the same object to all function calls which should write to it, or you could try the constructor that uses an `OutputStream` instead.

---

Another option would be to store all the nodes in a `LinkedList` or similar structure, which you pass to the function (similarly to the way `printStream` was above), and then you can simply iterate through that afterwards and write the nodes to file.

```
public void inOrderTraverseTree (Node focusNode, LinkedList<Node> output) {
    if (focusNode != null){
        inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild, output);
        output.add(focusNode);
        inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild, output);
    }//end if
}//end inOrderTraverseTree
```

Call with:

```
LinkedList<Node> output = new LinkedList<Node>();
inOrderTraverseTree(root, output);
// iterate through 'output' and write it to file
```

You could return the `LinkedList` instead of passing it around with a few changes to the code.

This is a bit more complex, but does give your code more modularity - it's probably better if a function to traverse a `LinkedList` doesn't concern itself with file I/O, but, on the other hand, the code you're writing probably isn't of the scale (in terms of code size and lifetime) that you need to worry about that (although you tend to end up doing what you do in your smaller projects in your larger projects as well, and smaller projects can become large quickly).

Comment: The sysout() is there just to display the list for now, I am trying to convert that to use something like a BufferedWriter or some type of `outputStream`. So would I have to write the files inside the traversal methods, or could I have a separate method to call those methods and write it that way? I feel like if I were to call it inside the sort methods it would just re-write the same line over and over again?

Comment: I mentioned two options in my answer - the first function I provided does the writing inside the function - this is similar to `System.out.println`, it just uses something else instead of `System.out`, which hopefully should be easy enough to see why it won't print the same line over and over again. The other option is to store all the elements in a collection to be printed later (added some code for that) - but I'm not really sure why you'd want to use this option, unless you want to have a collection for some other purpose.

Comment: Ok I see what you're saying. that pretty much answers it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you need to save the tree to file and later load that tree. You can approach like this.

- To save the tree, generate the inorder traversal along with preorder/postorder and save to file
- To load, read from the file and reconstruct same tree uniquely using two traversals.([Example](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-tree-from-given-inorder-and-preorder-traversal/))

You can use same traversal function with a flag

```
public void inOrderTraverseTree (Node focusNode, boolean toSave) {
    if (focusNode != null){
        inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild);            
        if(toSave)
           //write to file
        else
        System.out.println(focusNode);

        inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild);
    }//end if
}//end inOrderTraverseTree
```

Comment: Yes essentially that is what I'm looking to do.. so I would need to open my file writer in the traversal methods? There is no way that I can have a separate method that will call the traverse method and write it into a file?

Comment: Either you can write to file directly in traversal methods or make your traversal method return a `List` of nodes , which you can write to file outside of traversal method.