# How to load file to binary search tree in java

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, load, binary-tree

I need to save the tree to file and later load that tree. To save my tree i have use this function and it worked. But i don't know how to write function load that tree again from file.

## Write tree to file:

```
public void inOrderTraverseTree (Node focusNode, PrintStream printStream) {
            if (focusNode != null){
                inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.left, printStream);
                printStream.println(focusNode);
                inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.right, printStream);
            }//end if
        }//end inOrderTraverseTree
```

## And this is how i called it:

```
inOrderTraverseTree(root, new PrintStream("tree.txt"));
```

Comment: Have you read this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015827/save-load-contents-of-binary-search-tree

Comment: yeah i have write function save base on dat post but i still don't know how to load it again.

Comment: what do you mean by loading it again?Please clarify

Comment: i want to load my tree.txt to the the tree. I want to input the tree.txt to my tree when i run.

Comment: **Note that the new call will clear out the file before starting, so you'd probably want to store the PrintStream in a temporary variable, passing the same object to all function calls which should write to it, or you could try the constructor that uses an OutputStream instead.**

Comment: If you will read the answer; It is clearly mentioned that create an object type variable and store the `PrintStream` object in there

Comment: Can you give me an example. I still cannot do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save/load contents of binary search tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015827/save-load-contents-of-binary-search-tree)

Comment: Yeah i have already read Save/load contents of binary search tree answer but i still cannot do the load function. Can somebody give me an example ?